# Can we use LASSO for non-linear regression?

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning

I am studying machine learning and would like to apply LASSO. I wonder if it is possible to apply LASSO on a non-linear regression model. I search on the internet but all literature focus on linear setting. If we can apply LASSO on non-linear regression model, are there any relevant references I can follow?

Comment: If you can linearize the model, then yes but for an approximate solution in the LS sense since what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms. If you model is nonlinear because of **one** parameter, there are things which can be done. If you have a specific problem in mind, just tell us what it is. But, in a general manner, the answer would be NO.

Comment: Using $\ell_1$-norm penalties to promote sparsity is a big theme in optimization. For just one example in a nonlinear setting, deep learning frameworks such as tensorflow support $\ell_1$-norm regularization.

Comment: It seems the name LASSO is used for also nonlinear objectives. See the rrgularizing term as an "add-on". But I think it would be much harder to solve, in general.

Comment: Here's an example I found by googling for "nonlinear lasso": https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375809003528

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you be able to?

The essential part of LASSO is just adding an L$^1$ norm of the coefficients to the main term,

$$f(x,y,\beta) + \lambda\|\beta\|_1.$$

There's no reason $f$ has to be a linear model. It may not have an analytic solution, or be convex, but there's nothing stopping you from trying it out, and it should still induce sparsity, contingent on a large enough lambda.

Comment: I do not think it wouldn't be. I understand we can extend from linear to nonlinear model, but I am curious why no relevant literature can be found for nonlinear function when applying LASSO.

Comment: Are there any related references talking about LASSO on non-linear model?

Comment: @will_cheuk The name "Lasso" specifically refers to the problem of minimizing $(1/2) \| Ax- b \|_2^2 + \lambda \| x\|_1$. Try searching for terms like "$\ell_1$-norm regularization" or "sparsity" to find examples that are like Lasso but with a nonlinear model.